# How can i get sum of total row values in a row by using group by?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```sql
select customerid,
       (rentaldropoffdate - rentalpickupdate) as days,
       sum(
         RENTALINSURANCEADDITIONALCOST
         + (CATEGORYDAILYRENTALRATE * (rentaldropoffdate - rentalpickupdate))
       ) AS TOTAL_DUE
from   rental,
       vehiclerentalcategory,
       rentalinsuranceoption,
       VEHICLE
where  rental.vehicleid = vehicle.vehicleid
and    rental.rentalinsuranceoptionid = rentalinsuranceoption.rentalinsuranceoptionid
and    vehicle.VEHICLERENTALCATEGORYID = VEHICLERENTALCATEGORY.VEHICLERENTALCATEGORYid 
group by 
       customerid,
       (rentaldropoffdate - rentalpickupdate)
ORDER BY
       TOTAL_DUE desc;
```

[image: The result comes out this.]

so how can i have the sum of TOTAL_DUE of Customerid 1 in a row instead of two separate values?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with the `days` value.

Comment: A little table alias goes a long way.

Comment: As you can see, customerid = 1 have two results. i want to merge them in a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Sum the `rentaldropoffdate - rentalpickupdate` value rather than using it in the `GROUP BY`:

```sql
select customerid,
       SUM(rentaldropoffdate - rentalpickupdate) as days,
       SUM(
         RENTALINSURANCEADDITIONALCOST
         + (CATEGORYDAILYRENTALRATE * (rentaldropoffdate - rentalpickupdate))
       ) AS TOTAL_DUE
from   rental r
       INNER JOIN VEHICLE v
       ON ( r.vehicleid = v.vehicleid )
       INNER JOIN rentalinsuranceoption rio
       ON ( r.rentalinsuranceoptionid = rio.rentalinsuranceoptionid )
       INNER JOIN vehiclerentalcategory vrc
       ON ( v.VEHICLERENTALCATEGORYID = vrc.VEHICLERENTALCATEGORYid )
group by 
       customerid
ORDER BY
       TOTAL_DUE desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a sum on the days and remove days from the group by.

```sql
select customerid,
       sum(rentaldropoffdate - rentalpickupdate) as days,
       sum(
         RENTALINSURANCEADDITIONALCOST
         + (CATEGORYDAILYRENTALRATE * (rentaldropoffdate - rentalpickupdate))
       ) AS TOTAL_DUE
from   rental,
       vehiclerentalcategory,
       rentalinsuranceoption,
       VEHICLE
where  rental.vehicleid = vehicle.vehicleid
and    rental.rentalinsuranceoptionid = rentalinsuranceoption.rentalinsuranceoptionid
and    vehicle.VEHICLERENTALCATEGORYID = VEHICLERENTALCATEGORY.VEHICLERENTALCATEGORYid 
group by 
       customerid
ORDER BY
       TOTAL_DUE desc;
```